# PyCharm project files have disappeared

Tags: python, linux, pycharm

I was working on a python project in [JetBrains PyCharm 2016.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) on Lubuntu and all of a sudden, all my project files have disappeared from the IDE.

I have tried the following with no success:

1. Exit PyCharm, navigate to project root, delete the .idea file, open PyCharm, create a new project from the current projects source.
   ***Result: seems to load fine, but cannot see any project files in either "Project" view or individually load and view any files.***
2. Fresh download and run of PyCharm, repeating the above step.
   ***Result: Same as option 1.***
3. Using `File > Open` to open the project again.
   ***Result: Same as option 1.***

I can do a search by file or class name within PyCharm and the search does find the files. But on selecting one to load from the search results, the search dialogue just closes and the file is not loaded.

Also to clarify, I still have the files on disk in the project root physically. But PyCharm is not displaying them in the IDE.

Comment: Do you know any of the filenames in your project so that you can search for it on disk?

Comment: Are you saying the files are gone completely and you do not know where to find them?

Comment: Wow, just had this same behaviour. Side-by-side I can see the directory on my disk, PyCharm "open" window is just like "nope, that directory does not exist for me". I watched my directory bloop out of existance in PyCharm, while still being fine actually on my disk. OSX M1 over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have found the issue, which turned out to be indirect in the end. I just installed the latest updates for Lubuntu, restarted the PC, then opened PyCharm and like magic all my project files are now visible!

I know it was not just the restart because I had already tried that. So it must have been one or more of the updates. I'm not going to list all the updates here, there were a lot, but this solved my issue anyway.

Comment: Hi @Jeremy I have the same issue on Mac OS Mojave (version 1.14.6) What would you advise?

Comment: As it turns out, problems may occur when storing the project's files in the iCloud Drive. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206403299-Access-project-stored-in-iCloud-on-OS-X

Comment: I have the same issue with ubuntu 18.04.6 and Pycharm 2021. I tried all the tips nothing is working!

Answer (score 22):

I had the issue with PyCharm 2020.3.5 on macOS Big Sur 11.1.

My solution was:

1. `Preference -> Project: <ProjectName> -> Project structure`
2. Click `+ Add Content Root` at the right pane and select my project directory in a file browser

Comment: I have the same issue as OP, and this did not solve the problem. The Content Root was already the project directory, and even by removing it and adding it again the files don't show up in the project tool window.

Comment: I found this issue initially happened because my project name was different to the project-folder name - this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
Go to `File -> Open recent` you should see a list of your recent projects there. If you still don't see it there then just reopen the project by going to `File -> Open` and go to the location where you saved your project.

Comment: Thanks but I've already tried that and it has the same outcome as described in step 1 of my question unfortunately. in terms of being able to see the file being opened. It looks like it loads, but it never appears in the IDE. Plus I'm not talking about a single file here I'm talking about the entire project content not appearing.

Comment: I realise my last comment was a little muddled, sorry. In summary, I tried `File > Open` to open the project, but it did not solve my issue.

Comment: It's possible that your import settings might have been disturbed. Try uninstalling and reinstalling PyCharm. Or try installing a different IDE such as PyDev and see if you can import the project.

Comment: As stated in my question, i have already tried reinstalling pycharm. plus i have posted an answer now that it turned out to be a OS update in the end. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart with Clear file system cache... enabled.
If it doesn't help, is your home directory entirely local? Not a network mount of any type?
Also, have you tried 2021.3 EAP?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).