# PyCharm doesn’t see files in project

Tags: python, pycharm, ide

I commited changes in project, then I removed idea and cache folders, after that (or maybe this is not the reason) pycharm doesn’t see files in project: some files marked in yellow and no folders and .py files at all. Also there is no project structure and interpreter in settings
[image]
[image]
[image]

How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: The .idea folder contains the IntelliJ project-specific settings that you have removed. Now you can close Pycharm, manually delete the .idea folder from the directory, and reopen the project and configure it agian.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `computer-vision` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @Neighbourhood if my answer solved your problem , please accept it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Close PyCharm then delete the folder `.idea/` again,then open PyCharm and re-open the project .

To not lose preferences, you can go to `Preference -> Project: <ProjectName> -> Project structure` and click `+ Add Content Root` at the right pane and select my project directory in a file browser

Comment: This answer is not helpful because it deletes your preferences.  The correct answer  is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66876859